# How do I change the encoding on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, configuration

When I create a new row into my DataBase, I got these weird characters (from a String-type). I can not find how to fix this for 3 days. How do I change the encoding on Eclipse?

I did all of these configurations:

[image]

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [siteduzero.com](https://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/388001_389000/388661.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [siteduzero.com](https://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/388001_389000/388660.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [siteduzero.com](https://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/388001_389000/388659.png))</sub>

And

```
Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > 'Other UTF-8'
```

But, I still get this on my webpage which I had extracted from my database, knowing that the encoding there is perfect (JSP page):

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/136324Capturer4.jpg

and I wrote this in the top of my JSP page:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

and this into head tags of my page

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over. If a question didn't get the proper respose, edit and improve it. If you can't seem to find a previously asked question back, click the link behind your username in gray top bar.

Comment: What encoding are you using to read text from your database?

Comment: @nitind, utf-8 as i think

Answer (score 0):

I think that all this configuration is for new files created by Eclipse. If you have created your page before changing the configuration or if it was generated elsewhere, you have to change the encoding for the file. For example, right-click on the file in the Package explorer and chose Properties. You will find the configuration property "Text file encoding" for the specific file.
[image]

Comment: OP told that she got data from DB (in other words, data is not hardcoded in JSP). Hint: she told nowhere that she has set DB/JDBC encoding right.

Comment: When I create a new row into my DataBase, I got these weird characters (from a String-type). I can't find how to fix this :'(